# Display user name in laravel notification blade laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5, notifications, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I use standard Laravel notification table. in `data` column i have

```
{"type":"New Appointment","project":"1","assign_to":"80"}
```

And in notification blade

```
{{ $notification->data['type'] }} for {{ $notification->data['assign_to'] }}
```

This displays as

```
New Appointment for 80
```

But i want to join `data['assign_to'}` with `User` model and get `user_name`. Which displays as

```
New Appointment for John
```

What is the best way to use Eloquent in Laravel view

Comment: Can you how your full notification class? This class already has the `$notifiable` user available when you are sending the notification so their should be no need to assign the `ID` in the notification data.

Comment: when new task is assigned i am sending db notifications for assigned user as well as all the admins. Therefore i need to show admins what task assigned to which user. That user is the $notification->data['assign_to'] not $notifiable

Comment: You could use `User::find($notification->data['assign_to'])` to find the user by the ID.

Comment: do you mean, in the controller or view?. I can do it in the controller. but wanna save user_id not user_name

Comment: You could do it in the controller and assign this to a variable so you can pass it through to your view.